# How to add custom fields to stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using stripe.js, got this:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Your email</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="email">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
<% end %>
```

How do I add new fields to submit to stripe? such as name, address, etc. I think it has something to do with changing data-stripe but I couldn't find a "list" of the values that stripe accepts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) Updatable Stripe objects (Account, Charge, Customer, Refund, Subscription, and Transfer) have a metadata parameter. You can use this parameter to attach key-value data to these Stripe objects.

You can check [HERE](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges) for the list of attributes of the Charge object.

In your question you refer to some attributes which can be better related to the user (Customer) rather than the Charge itself.

You can check [HERE](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) for the list of attributes of the Customer object.

You can use something like the following in your controller:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => params[:email],
  :source  => params[:stripeToken],
  :metadata => {
    :address => params[:address],
    :city => params[:city],
    :region => params[:region],
    :country => params[:country]
  }
)
```